# Update a single list item of a Mongo DB document

Tags: mongodb

I have the following document structure inside a mongodb collection:

```
{ _id: XXX, Name: "Example", References: [ { RefId: YYY, RefCount: 2 }, ...] }
```

What puzzles me, is how to write a update() operation that increments exactly one of the reference Ids (RefId) by one. The document that needs an update to its references will be identified by its _id field.

I know about the possibility to replace the entire document, but if possible I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `$` [positional operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator) in your `update` to identify the element in the array that your query parameter matched.

So something like:

```
t.update({_id: XXX, 'References.RefId': YYY}, {$inc: {'References.$.RefCount': 1}});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! The documentation you provided states the the $ can't be combined with an upsert. So I guess there is no possibility to write a query that increments a list object by one (if found) or inserts a ist object with a count of one?

Comment: That's correct.  Here's the jira for that feature: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3326